# MATLAB: How to include determinant in LU decomposition

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have this code for LU decomposition but I want to include determinant of L and U so that the output will be determinant of LU or determinant of PLU.

```
function [ P, L, U ] = LUdecomposition(A) 
  A=input('matrix A =');
  m = size(A);
  n = m(1);
  L = eye(n);
  P = eye(n);
  U = A;
  for i=1:m(1)
    if U(i,i)==0
      maximum = max(abs(U(i:end,1)));
      for k=1:n
        if maximum == abs(U(k,i))
          temp = U(1,:);
          U(1,:) = U(k,:);
          U(k,:) = temp;
          temp = P(:,1);
          P(1,:) = P(k,:);
          P(k,:) = temp;
        end
      end
    end
    if U(i,i)~=1
      temp = eye(n);
      temp(i,i)=U(i,i);
      L = L * temp;
      U(i,:) = U(i,:)/U(i,i); 
    end
    if i~=m(1)
      for j=i+1:length(U)
        temp = eye(n);
        temp(j,i) = U(j,i);
        L = L * temp;
        U(j,:) = U(j,:)-U(j,i)*U(i,:);
      end
    end
  end
  P = P';
end
```

Comment: what do you mean by including the determinant? You mean adding to the output arguments ?

Comment: I mean instead of the output to be P=P', I want the output as det(LU)

Comment: `function [ P, L, U , detLU] = LUdecomposition(A) ......... detLU = det(L*U) end`

Answer (score 0):

L and U are triangular matrices. So their determinants are the product of the diagonal elements. In a classical LU decomposition the diagonal elements of L are 1, therefore det(L) = 1. Because of A = L*U => det(A) = det(L)*det(U) you can easily compute the determinant of LU by computing the determinant of U. Therefore det(PLU) = + or - det(LU). I'm not sure how to figure it out :/

Comment: Yes, I know L and U are triangular matrix and det(LU) = det(L) * det(U) but how will I include it in the code above